# Pass a row of a multidimensional array as a parameter

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, casting, compiler-warnings

My program in C has a 3D array defined as `int origF [6][6][4]`. I also have a function `void displayPM (int tile [])`, to which I pass `origF [i][j]` as an argument, which logically makes a sense. It works as it should (when `displayPM` reads `tile [k]` it gets the value `origF [i][j][k]`. However, the compiler (it was Turbo C++ in VirtualBox) issues a warning **Suspicious pointer conversion** with explanation: *The compiler encountered some conversion of a pointer that caused the pointer to point to a different type. You should use a cast to suppress this warning if the conversion is proper.*

Realising that just like one-dimensional array, a milti-dimensional array is just a pointer to the beginning of the data, what type is then `origF [i][j]`? As it's working correctly, it's still a pointer, and it points to `origF [i][j][0]`, but wrong type? Or is it an issue with the compiler?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: "it was Turbo C++". That's your problem right here. Why are you using a piece if sofrware that was already obsolete in the last millennium?

Answer (score 1):

> Realising that just like one-dimensional array, a milti-dimensional array is just a pointer to the beginning of the data

No. Not in the case of one **or** multidimensional arrays. An arrays **is** the block of data. It is not a pointer. It does *convert* to a pointer to the first element when used in most other expressions (even `origF[i]` is in fact `*(origF + i)`), but it is not a pointer itself.

`origF` is an array. When you index into it, it gets converted to a pointer to an array for that purpose. It becomes `int (*)[6][4]`. You can create such pointers too.

```
int (*p)[6][4] = origF; // Here origF is decaying to a pointer to its first element.
```

And when that is dereferenced, you obtain an expression of an array type, `int[6][4]`. That also happens "recursively" for as many dimensions as one needs.

So back to your example, you wanted to know what `origF [i][j]` is. It's an expression that has array type. The type is `int[4]`. When you pass it to a function, it is automatically converted to an `int*`.

That's at the language level, something the compiler authors seem not aware of at the time. There is no suspicious conversion going on. The only suspicions should be aimed at whoever programmed that warning. It actually suggests you add a cast (I.e. just silence it) and potentially break your program. Not that there is anything wrong with what you did, again, but that is very bad advice in general.

Anyway, since TurboC is discontinued, you'd be far better off with a modern compiler. GCC and Clang are both Free and Open source software respectively, and they have a very high QoI. You should give them a look.

Comment: @Heimdall - You don't have to follow the advice to choose a modern a compiler. But I will be remiss not to mention it.

Comment: I was just messing around with the DOS virtual machine and the only C compiler I could think of for DOS was Turbo. So I take it the warning was just a compiler issue... I will steer clear of it though for anything serious, especially as it seems prone to crashing.

Comment: @Heimdall - Besides that, C has evolved since TurboC last had a major update. You'd be missing on a lot of modern ways to write clear and expressive code. Another point to consider.

Comment: I also don't know why you want to program for dos, but you can do development for windows. Microsoft offers Visual Studio community edition. It's ways better than TurboC, and you don't need to mess with a virtual machine.

Comment: I know, it's quite an old one, version 3. But I was just messing about with something quick that was at hand, and the program was a simple command line with text display.

Comment: Even the Windows SDK 7.1 will get you the VS2010 compiler (in less than 1G) which is about 21 years more current than TurboC as will MinGW (which will provide gcc 6.X)